# Edit new calendar entries on AT&T samsung galaxy s2 using android 4.0.3

Tags: calendar

The 'edit' button does not appear when trying to edit a new calendar entry using the 4.0.3 ice cream sandwich operating system on my AT&T Samsung Galaxy 2 phone.  The calendar entries that were imported from gingerbread allow me to edit the entries.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround I've found is to sync the phone calendar with Kies to Outlook calendar and edit in Outlook then resync. The edited update is then picked up by the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the actual event and then the menu button.

Goto `Calendar -> Click day -> Click thru event -> Click the menu button -> Click edit`